# Dynamic Bootstrap division to look like a two column table

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, bootstrap-4

so I have searched online but cannot get what I am looking for, also forgive me because I did not really know how to give this a clear title as what I want is specific.

I have loads of data (from sqlserver db) that I want to display to the users of my site, I decided that the best way to show the data is in a two column format so Left and Right of which all are divisions.

```
<div class="leftCol">
  <div class="row" id="left1" runat="server">
    <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5">Title</div>
    <div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-7 col-md-7 col-lg-7">Data</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" id="left2" runat="server">
    <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5">Title</div>
    <div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-7 col-md-7 col-lg-7">Data</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" id="left3" runat="server">
    <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5">Title</div>
    <div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-7 col-md-7 col-lg-7">Data</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="rightCol">
  <div class="row" id="right1" runat="server">
    <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5">Title</div>
    <div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-7 col-md-7 col-lg-7">Data</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" id="right2" runat="server">
    <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5">Title</div>
    <div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-7 col-md-7 col-lg-7">Data</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" id="right3" runat="server">
    <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5">Title</div>
    <div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-7 col-md-7 col-lg-7">Data</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This should give me something like the following

[image]

Now if you look closely (I know its hard to tell) but there is a clear separation between the left and right columns (in place of a border).

The problem is however while this works, all of my data rows can be made invisible in the tune of left1.visible = false or display = none for when there is no data attached to it. so we get a weird looking grid that looks like the following.

[image]

Now I think it would be better if everything was to shift upwards so it looked like the following

[image]

However I am unsure on how to do the borders for this, so I am thinking I can remove the left and right division and using bootstrap columns I can manipulate it so each data row division is 6 columns big so that way i will always get two on one row if needed.

```
 <div class="container">
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6" id="data1" runat="server">
        <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5">Title</div>
        <div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-7 col-md-7 col-lg-7">Data</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6" id="data2" runat="server">
        <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5">Title</div>
        <div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-7 col-md-7 col-lg-7">Data</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6" id="data3" runat="server">
        <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5">Title</div>
        <div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-7 col-md-7 col-lg-7">Data</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6" id="data4" runat="server">
        <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5">Title</div>
        <div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-7 col-md-7 col-lg-7">Data</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6" id="data5" runat="server">
        <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5">Title</div>
        <div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-7 col-md-7 col-lg-7">Data</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6" id="data6" runat="server">
        <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5">Title</div>
        <div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-7 col-md-7 col-lg-7">Data</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Using this any rows (are now columns) and are missing will not matter and I will get the desired effect, however except one thing how do I border this, I can go down the route of giving a border to the whole rows (now columns) but then how do I deal with the last one if the number of data elements has an odd number. Plus that would mean the borders between cross section of the div's border will be stronger than the outside as you will have a border from the left, right, bottom and top.

Does anyone have a clue how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone out there I managed to find a solution for my problem and thought it would be better shared in case anyone else runs into the same issue. So after researching and playing around I managed to style majority of the divisions via css by using the following elements to make the border 0.

```
div[class^="col"]
```

With this you can specify the first column, last column even numbered ones. Therefore I was able to switch the border on and off for specific divisions.

I would say my solution was a lot more complex, as having things shift upwards or sideways depending if data is missing created more issues for the user. What we eventually decided was to have left and right cols as per our previous attempt but have it so we can balance both the left and right rows. So if we had 8 rows in total there would be 4 in each. If we had 9 then 5 in the left and 4 in the right and so on.

I did this by adding a left and right repeater to repeat the rows from our first attempt and in code had the following to split the datatable in two.

```
 int totalRows = dt.Rows.Count;
 int halfway = (int)Math.Ceiling((float)totalRows / 2);
 LeftDataTable = dt.AsEnumerable().Take(halfway).CopyToDataTable();
 RightDataTable = dt.AsEnumerable().Skip(halfway).Take(totalRows - halfway).CopyToDataTable();
```

Using this I can now add it to our repeater, so regardless of how many rows we have in total to show it will always balance out the  the left and right columns.